# Excel VBA - Hiding processing from the user

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I know this has been asked previously on various forums (I've been looking at this issue for a bit) and so I have the feeling the answer might be "no", but I want to make sure I'm on the right track. I have some pretty large workbooks to process (about 1.5M records) that involves VBA accessing the Windows file system - not really relevant here but it does mean its a long process (about 4 hours).

The issue is whether or not the VBA can be run without the user seeing/noticing anything happening on the screen. I always incorporate the following code at the start of a Module so that it can run as best it can:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
Application.EnableEvents = False  
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual  
Application.DisplayAlerts = False  
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False  
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False  
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
```

The code involves opening workbooks, saving them, reading and writing data from the Windows file system to workbooks and between workbooks. Nevertheless, there is still an annoying Excel workbook on the screen (albeit totally blank) which flashes/blinks at times. The 'issue' is that at certain times Excel will do something (I'm guessing something like a workbook open or a save) and it will interrupt the user which we don't want to happen. Can it be be coded so that the user is never interrupted while the code is running?

I have tried the following when creating a new workbook but it ended up with no data in it at the end of the process, so I put that down as a fail.

```
Dim wkb2 As Workbook

...

Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Add
wkb2.Windows(1).Visible = False
```

Comment: You could spawn a new `Excel.Application` instance (e.g. `Set app = New Excel.Application`), set `app.Visible = False`, and then use that object to qualify that `Workbooks` call (i.e. `app.Workbooks`), and do `app.Quit` when the processing is done.

Comment: "but it ended up with no data in it" - if you have unqualified `Range` calls anywhere, they're implicit member calls against whatever the `ActiveSheet` is (unless you're in a worksheet module - in which case they're just `Me.Range` calls); same with any unqualified `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns`, `Names` member calls. If it says `On Error Resume Next` anywhere, remove it: it's probably hiding a run-time error 1004 caused by these unqualified calls, which would explain the missing data... assuming the data didn't end up written into an unexpected other workbook.

Comment: Hit F2 to bring up the *Object Browser*; select `Excel` from the dropdown in the top section, then locate the `Application` class in the left pane: the right pane will list all the visible members, and a lot of these members are mirrored in the hidden `Globals` module. `ActiveWindow` would be in there: you'll want to qualify all these member calls with the `app` object, otherwise you'll be referring to *your* global instance of `Excel.Application`, rather than the instance you're trying to automate. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56122859/1188513) for more info on the *object browser*.